# Security test revealed my android app has a predictable random number generator, which is risky. It belongs to the core Kotlin libraries. How to fix?

Tags: android, kotlin

I ran a security test via the `ImmuniWeb` tool on my Android app APK. One of the observations the tool made was that one of the app components uses a predictable random number generator. It further said:

> Under certain conditions, this weakness may jeopardize mobile
>   application data encryption or other protection based on
>   randomization. For example, if encryption tokens are generated inside
>   of the application and an attacker can provide the application with a
>   predictable token to validate and then execute a sensitive activity
>   within the application or its backend.
>
> Example of insecure code: 
>   Random random = new Random()
>
> Example of secure code:
>   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom()
>
> There is 'new Random()' found in file 'kotlinx/coroutines/scheduling/CoroutineScheduler.java'
>
> There is 'new Random()' found in file 'kotlin/random/FallbackThreadLocalRandom$implStorage$1.java'

The app heavily uses Kotlin coroutines so I am not in a position to remove the library. My doubt is how do I avoid this vulnerability? Can I do something about it? Lastly, if this really is a valid risky code, can we report and expect Kotlin to push an update to fix it?

Comment: You might want to at least state which security tool you are using and what vulnerability you think exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, @MorrisonChang, let me edit the question and add this detail.

Comment: Personally I don't think it is a vulnerability and the just the tool generating incorrect flags. I don't know how random numbers in operational code for coroutines (lightweight threads) would relate to encryption of application data. You are free to investigate the source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: Did you get any response yet?

Comment: No, I haven't... In case you have an answer, please post it here. If it answers my question, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Morrison Chang .  I don't think the coroutine scheduling code needs to be cryptographically secure either.

That logic isn't doing something like creating initialisation vectors for a block cipher etc. so it ought to be fine...